# why is JsError converted to JsSuccess of default?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I am using Play-Json **2.6.3**  `WithDefaultValues` as below

```
implicit def jsonFormatFoo = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Foo]

 implicit def jsonFormatBar = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Bar]
```

But it gives unexpected behavior for :

```
case class Bar(name:String)
case class Foo(bars: List[Bars] = List.empty)
```

Now if I do

```
val result = Json.parse("""{"bars":[{"name":null}]}""").validate[Foo]

println(result)
```

I get `JsSuccess(Foo(List()),)`. I was expecting `JsError(List((/bars(0)/name,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsstring),WrappedArray())))))` which only comes once I remove the default `List.empty`.

If I have a default, why is JsError converted to JsSuccess of the default value ? Its bit unintuitive. How do I resolve it ?

Comment: Please indicate lib versions

Comment: I am using play json 2.6 as with default values is in it.

Comment: With play-json:2.6.13 and yours code from the above. I am getting error: `JsError(List((JsPath(List(KeyPathNode("bars"), IdxPathNode(0), KeyPathNode("name"))), List(JsonValidationError(List("error.expected.jsstring"), WrappedArray())))))`. What is patch version of you Play-Json dependency 2.6.x? x - is what?

Comment: i am using play-json = 2.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some change starting version Play-JSON 2.6.8. If you switch to it or to higher version, then it should start complain on `null` value for Bar:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.8"

@ import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

@  case class Bar(name:String)
defined class Bar

@  case class Foo(bars: List[Bar] = List.empty)
defined class Foo

@ implicit def jsonFormatBar = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Bar]
defined function jsonFormatBar

@ implicit def jsonFormatFoo = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Foo]
defined function jsonFormatFoo

@ Json.parse("""{"bars":[{"name":null}]}""").validate[Foo]
res6: JsResult[Foo] = JsError(List((JsPath(List(KeyPathNode("bars"), IdxPathNode(0), KeyPathNode("name"))), List(JsonValidationError(List("error.expected.jsstring"), WrappedArray())))))
```

Comment: Thanks Ill bump the version and try.